# How can I Access one folder to another in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Project path on local **C:\xampp\htdocs\ABCProject.**

And similarly Other Project **C:\xampp\htdocs\XYZProject.**

Now Can I use ABC folder package package1 used into XYz Project.???

But package one will write only 1 time. **Don't be copied in ABC ana XYZ project both.**

Comment: If possible you could always just make these packages into composer packages and pull them in that way?

Comment: I have 3 package named like one Admin, second for REST API and third for Common functions.All three are different Projects not in same folder. now I want use common functions in both folder API and admin side.Than how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can so long as the web server has access to both directories, which it should. IF you have a php class in ABCProject and you want to include it in XYZProject, you can include it like this.

```
dirname(__FILE__)."/../ABCProject/class.php"
```

The important thing to know is that using `../` in a file path will make it go back 1 directory. So if you use `../` at the start of a directory path string, it will actually go back a directory.

Comment: I want include only packages from one folder to another

Comment: as in all packages from one directory to be included into another? If so, you might be better off using a symbolic link. Either way, the code above will do what you asked? The language you use isnt very clear, so be more specific if you want me to give further details

Comment: I made this code in PHP laravel.Eg. Simply I will made a Package P1 and that package will used in Project ABC and XYZ both.But the PAckage P1 is also in other folder. And Package code will write only 1 time.

Comment: I have 3 package named like one Admin, second for REST API and third for Common functions.All three are different Projects not in same folder. now I want use common functions in both folder API and admin side.Than how can I do that ?